# pandoc-crossref subfigure references are off by one when using ruled style

Tags: cross-referencing, subfloats, pandoc

I am using pandoc (version 2.19.2) to write a document. I want to use the `ruled` float style, similar to the style which is automatically applied for `pandoc-crossref` code blocks (which are converted to `codelisting` floats). The `float` package documentation says to use these commands to apply this style to figures and tables:

```
\floatstyle{ruled}
\restylefloat{figure}
\restylefloat{table}
```

However, once I added these commands to my template, all subfigure references are one lower than they should be.

Here is an example (`image.png` is just a [placeholder](https://via.placeholder.com/100x100) - any image will work):

```
---
subfigGrid: true
lof: true
---

\floatstyle{ruled}
\restylefloat{figure}
\restylefloat{table}

# My first chapter

This is an intro chapter. It references [@fig:example1], [@fig:example2a] and also [@fig:example2b].

![Image 1](image.png){#fig:example1}

<div id="fig:example2">
![Image 2a](image.png){#fig:example2a width=45%}
![Image 2b](image.png){#fig:example2b width=45%}

Example with subfigures
</div>
```

This is the build command:

```
pandoc --filter=pandoc-crossref --citeproc --standalone --pdf-engine=xelatex -o sample.pdf sample.md
```

Here is the rendered output:

- The List of Figures shows the correct numbers
- The captions show the correct numbers
- The references in the text do not:

[image: output]

Notice that it says `fig. 1.1a` and `fig. 1.1b` where it should say `1.2a` and `1.2b`.

I assume there's some conflict between the `\restylefloat` command and the `pandoccrossref` reference counter, but I have no idea how to solve this.

How can I use this style and keep the reference numbers correct?

---

UPDATE: Here is the generated TeX output (using `pandoc --filter=pandoc-crossref --citeproc --standalone -o sample.tex sample.md`

```
% Options for packages loaded elsewhere
\PassOptionsToPackage{unicode}{hyperref}
\PassOptionsToPackage{hyphens}{url}
%
\documentclass[
]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{iftex}
\ifPDFTeX
  \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
  \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
  \usepackage{textcomp} % provide euro and other symbols
\else % if luatex or xetex
  \usepackage{unicode-math}
  \defaultfontfeatures{Scale=MatchLowercase}
  \defaultfontfeatures[\rmfamily]{Ligatures=TeX,Scale=1}
\fi
% Use upquote if available, for straight quotes in verbatim environments
\IfFileExists{upquote.sty}{\usepackage{upquote}}{}
\IfFileExists{microtype.sty}{% use microtype if available
  \usepackage[]{microtype}
  \UseMicrotypeSet[protrusion]{basicmath} % disable protrusion for tt fonts
}{}
\makeatletter
\@ifundefined{KOMAClassName}{% if non-KOMA class
  \IfFileExists{parskip.sty}{%
    \usepackage{parskip}
  }{% else
    \setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
    \setlength{\parskip}{6pt plus 2pt minus 1pt}}
}{% if KOMA class
  \KOMAoptions{parskip=half}}
\makeatother
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{longtable,booktabs,array}
\usepackage{calc} % for calculating minipage widths
% Correct order of tables after \paragraph or \subparagraph
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd\longtable{\par}{\if@noskipsec\mbox{}\fi\par}{}{}
\makeatother
% Allow footnotes in longtable head/foot
\IfFileExists{footnotehyper.sty}{\usepackage{footnotehyper}}{\usepackage{footnote}}
\makesavenoteenv{longtable}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\makeatletter
\def\maxwidth{\ifdim\Gin@nat@width>\linewidth\linewidth\else\Gin@nat@width\fi}
\def\maxheight{\ifdim\Gin@nat@height>\textheight\textheight\else\Gin@nat@height\fi}
\makeatother
% Scale images if necessary, so that they will not overflow the page
% margins by default, and it is still possible to overwrite the defaults
% using explicit options in \includegraphics[width, height, ...]{}
\setkeys{Gin}{width=\maxwidth,height=\maxheight,keepaspectratio}
% Set default figure placement to htbp
\makeatletter
\def\fps@figure{htbp}
\makeatother
\setlength{\emergencystretch}{3em} % prevent overfull lines
\providecommand{\tightlist}{%
  \setlength{\itemsep}{0pt}\setlength{\parskip}{0pt}}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{-\maxdimen} % remove section numbering
\makeatletter
\@ifpackageloaded{subfig}{}{\usepackage{subfig}}
\@ifpackageloaded{caption}{}{\usepackage{caption}}
\captionsetup[subfloat]{margin=0.5em}
\AtBeginDocument{%
\renewcommand*\figurename{Figure}
\renewcommand*\tablename{Table}
}
\AtBeginDocument{%
\renewcommand*\listfigurename{List of Figures}
\renewcommand*\listtablename{List of Tables}
}
\newcounter{pandoccrossref@subfigures@footnote@counter}
\newenvironment{pandoccrossrefsubfigures}{%
\setcounter{pandoccrossref@subfigures@footnote@counter}{0}
\begin{figure}\centering%
\gdef\global@pandoccrossref@subfigures@footnotes{}%
\DeclareRobustCommand{\footnote}[1]{\footnotemark%
\stepcounter{pandoccrossref@subfigures@footnote@counter}%
\ifx\global@pandoccrossref@subfigures@footnotes\empty%
\gdef\global@pandoccrossref@subfigures@footnotes{{##1}}%
\else%
\g@addto@macro\global@pandoccrossref@subfigures@footnotes{, {##1}}%
\fi}}%
{\end{figure}%
\addtocounter{footnote}{-\value{pandoccrossref@subfigures@footnote@counter}}
\@for\f:=\global@pandoccrossref@subfigures@footnotes\do{\stepcounter{footnote}\footnotetext{\f}}%
\gdef\global@pandoccrossref@subfigures@footnotes{}}
\@ifpackageloaded{float}{}{\usepackage{float}}
\floatstyle{ruled}
\@ifundefined{c@chapter}{\newfloat{codelisting}{h}{lop}}{\newfloat{codelisting}{h}{lop}[chapter]}
\floatname{codelisting}{Listing}
\newcommand*\listoflistings{\listof{codelisting}{List of Listings}}
\makeatother
\ifLuaTeX
  \usepackage{selnolig}  % disable illegal ligatures
\fi
\IfFileExists{bookmark.sty}{\usepackage{bookmark}}{\usepackage{hyperref}}
\IfFileExists{xurl.sty}{\usepackage{xurl}}{} % add URL line breaks if available
\urlstyle{same} % disable monospaced font for URLs
\hypersetup{
  hidelinks,
  pdfcreator={LaTeX via pandoc}}

\author{}
\date{}

\begin{document}

\listoffigures
\floatstyle{ruled}
\restylefloat{figure}
\restylefloat{table}

\hypertarget{my-first-chapter}{%
\section{My first chapter}\label{my-first-chapter}}

This is an intro chapter. It references fig.~\ref{fig:example1},
fig.~\ref{fig:example2a} and also fig.~\ref{fig:example2b}.

\begin{figure}
\hypertarget{fig:example1}{%
\centering
\includegraphics{image.png}
\caption{Image 1}\label{fig:example1}
}
\end{figure}

\begin{pandoccrossrefsubfigures}

\subfloat[Image
2a]{\includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth,height=\textheight]{image.png}\label{fig:example2a}}
\subfloat[Image
2b]{\includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth,height=\textheight]{image.png}\label{fig:example2b}}

\caption[{Example with subfigures}]{Example with subfigures}

\label{fig:example2}

\end{pandoccrossrefsubfigures}

\end{document}
```

---

UPDATE 2: I discovered that the `\restylefloat*` version of the command (which does not move the captions) does not cause this numbering problem, but I need to figure out how to handle the captions.

Answer (score 2):

The `pandoccrossref` reference counter seems to be fine, instead there seems to be an incompatibility between the `float` and the `subfig` package since this document results in the same incorrect behavior:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{float,subfig,graphicx}
\floatstyle{ruled}
\restylefloat{figure}
\begin{document}

\section{My first chapter}\label{my-first-chapter}

This is an intro chapter. It references fig.~\ref{fig:example1},
fig.~\ref{fig:example2a} and also fig.~\ref{fig:example2b}.

\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth]{example-image-a}
\caption{Image 1}\label{fig:example1}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\subfloat[Image 2a]{\includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth]{example-image-b}\label{fig:example2a}}
\subfloat[Image 2b]{\includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth]{example-image-b}\label{fig:example2b}}
\caption[{Example with subfigures}]{Example with subfigures}
\label{fig:example2}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

When I replace `\usepackage{float,subfig,graphicx}` with `\usepackage{float,subcaption,graphicx}` the result is correct, so you could create a local file `subfig.sty` with the contents

```
\ProvidesPackage{subfig}[2023/03/20 v1.0 subfig -> subcaption]
\expandafter\let\csname ver@subfig.sty\endcsname\@undefined % needed for older versions of subcaption package
\RequirePackageWithOptions{subcaption}
\endinput
```

as a (very) quick & dirty work-around.

Comment: When I try your workaround in my document, I get `! Package subcaption Error: This package can't be used in cooperation with the subfig package.`

Comment: @MosheKatz It works fine here. What version of the subcaption package are you using? My log says `Package: subcaption 2023/02/19 v1.6 Sub-captions (AR)`.

Comment: @MosheKatz It seems my work-around does not work with older versions of the subcaption package. I just revised it (in my answer), could you please test it again?

Comment: TeXLive 2022 ships with `2022/01/07 v1.5 Sub-captions (AR)`. I will test again with your changes.

Comment: This works! Now I need to decide if I prefer your answer which keeps the subcaptions on top, or my answer which puts them on the bottom.

Answer (score 1):

The maintainer of the `pandoc-crossref` project [gave me a workaround](https://github.com/lierdakil/pandoc-crossref/issues/382#issuecomment-1475821064) that uses `\captionsetup[figure]{position=bottom}` to move the subfigure captions below the figures. This fixes the figure counting:

```
---
subfigGrid: true
lof: true
header-includes: |
  \AtEndPreamble{%
  \floatstyle{ruled}
  \restylefloat{figure}
  \restylefloat{table}
  \captionsetup[figure]{position=bottom}
  }
---

# My first chapter

This is an intro chapter. It references [@fig:example1], [@fig:example2a] and also [@fig:example2b].

![Image 1](image.png){#fig:example1}

<div id="fig:example2">
![Image 2a](image.png){#fig:example2a width=45%}
![Image 2b](image.png){#fig:example2b width=45%}

Example with subfigures
</div>
```

Produces this TeX output:

```tex
% Options for packages loaded elsewhere
\PassOptionsToPackage{unicode}{hyperref}
\PassOptionsToPackage{hyphens}{url}
%
\documentclass[
]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{iftex}
\ifPDFTeX
  \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
  \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
  \usepackage{textcomp} % provide euro and other symbols
\else % if luatex or xetex
  \usepackage{unicode-math}
  \defaultfontfeatures{Scale=MatchLowercase}
  \defaultfontfeatures[\rmfamily]{Ligatures=TeX,Scale=1}
\fi
% Use upquote if available, for straight quotes in verbatim environments
\IfFileExists{upquote.sty}{\usepackage{upquote}}{}
\IfFileExists{microtype.sty}{% use microtype if available
  \usepackage[]{microtype}
  \UseMicrotypeSet[protrusion]{basicmath} % disable protrusion for tt fonts
}{}
\makeatletter
\@ifundefined{KOMAClassName}{% if non-KOMA class
  \IfFileExists{parskip.sty}{%
    \usepackage{parskip}
  }{% else
    \setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
    \setlength{\parskip}{6pt plus 2pt minus 1pt}}
}{% if KOMA class
  \KOMAoptions{parskip=half}}
\makeatother
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{longtable,booktabs,array}
\usepackage{calc} % for calculating minipage widths
% Correct order of tables after \paragraph or \subparagraph
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd\longtable{\par}{\if@noskipsec\mbox{}\fi\par}{}{}
\makeatother
% Allow footnotes in longtable head/foot
\IfFileExists{footnotehyper.sty}{\usepackage{footnotehyper}}{\usepackage{footnote}}
\makesavenoteenv{longtable}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\makeatletter
\def\maxwidth{\ifdim\Gin@nat@width>\linewidth\linewidth\else\Gin@nat@width\fi}
\def\maxheight{\ifdim\Gin@nat@height>\textheight\textheight\else\Gin@nat@height\fi}
\makeatother
% Scale images if necessary, so that they will not overflow the page
% margins by default, and it is still possible to overwrite the defaults
% using explicit options in \includegraphics[width, height, ...]{}
\setkeys{Gin}{width=\maxwidth,height=\maxheight,keepaspectratio}
% Set default figure placement to htbp
\makeatletter
\def\fps@figure{htbp}
\makeatother
\setlength{\emergencystretch}{3em} % prevent overfull lines
\providecommand{\tightlist}{%
  \setlength{\itemsep}{0pt}\setlength{\parskip}{0pt}}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{-\maxdimen} % remove section numbering
\AtEndPreamble{%
\floatstyle{ruled}
\restylefloat{figure}
\restylefloat{table}
\captionsetup[figure]{position=bottom}
}
\makeatletter
\@ifpackageloaded{subfig}{}{\usepackage{subfig}}
\@ifpackageloaded{caption}{}{\usepackage{caption}}
\captionsetup[subfloat]{margin=0.5em}
\AtBeginDocument{%
\renewcommand*\figurename{Figure}
\renewcommand*\tablename{Table}
}
\AtBeginDocument{%
\renewcommand*\listfigurename{List of Figures}
\renewcommand*\listtablename{List of Tables}
}
\newcounter{pandoccrossref@subfigures@footnote@counter}
\newenvironment{pandoccrossrefsubfigures}{%
\setcounter{pandoccrossref@subfigures@footnote@counter}{0}
\begin{figure}\centering%
\gdef\global@pandoccrossref@subfigures@footnotes{}%
\DeclareRobustCommand{\footnote}[1]{\footnotemark%
\stepcounter{pandoccrossref@subfigures@footnote@counter}%
\ifx\global@pandoccrossref@subfigures@footnotes\empty%
\gdef\global@pandoccrossref@subfigures@footnotes{{##1}}%
\else%
\g@addto@macro\global@pandoccrossref@subfigures@footnotes{, {##1}}%
\fi}}%
{\end{figure}%
\addtocounter{footnote}{-\value{pandoccrossref@subfigures@footnote@counter}}
\@for\f:=\global@pandoccrossref@subfigures@footnotes\do{\stepcounter{footnote}\footnotetext{\f}}%
\gdef\global@pandoccrossref@subfigures@footnotes{}}
\@ifpackageloaded{float}{}{\usepackage{float}}
\floatstyle{ruled}
\@ifundefined{c@chapter}{\newfloat{codelisting}{h}{lop}}{\newfloat{codelisting}{h}{lop}[chapter]}
\floatname{codelisting}{Listing}
\newcommand*\listoflistings{\listof{codelisting}{List of Listings}}
\makeatother
\ifLuaTeX
  \usepackage{selnolig}  % disable illegal ligatures
\fi
\IfFileExists{bookmark.sty}{\usepackage{bookmark}}{\usepackage{hyperref}}
\IfFileExists{xurl.sty}{\usepackage{xurl}}{} % add URL line breaks if available
\urlstyle{same} % disable monospaced font for URLs
\hypersetup{
  hidelinks,
  pdfcreator={LaTeX via pandoc}}

\author{}
\date{}

\begin{document}

\listoffigures
\hypertarget{my-first-chapter}{%
\section{My first chapter}\label{my-first-chapter}}

This is an intro chapter. It references fig.~\ref{fig:example1},
fig.~\ref{fig:example2a} and also fig.~\ref{fig:example2b}.

\begin{figure}
\hypertarget{fig:example1}{%
\centering
\includegraphics{image.png}
\caption{Image 1}\label{fig:example1}
}
\end{figure}

\begin{pandoccrossrefsubfigures}

\subfloat[Image
2a]{\includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth,height=\textheight]{image.png}\label{fig:example2a}}
\subfloat[Image
2b]{\includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth,height=\textheight]{image.png}\label{fig:example2b}}

\caption[{Example with subfigures}]{Example with subfigures}

\label{fig:example2}

\end{pandoccrossrefsubfigures}

\end{document}
```

And this rendered output:

[image: fixed output]